# Diff view for chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, diff

I was curious if we might be able to get a diff viewer in chat. Sometimes people come in asking questions about largish pieces of code. It'd be neat if there was a link next to these chunks of code that copies it into your text box and when you reply shows a diff of the two.

Just a thought. :)

Answer (score 10):

You should tell those people to **not** come in asking questions about largish pieces of code, and instead learn to create a minimum working example. There really is no other solution here.

If you still want to go out of your way to help them, then use your own diff. There are free services available online to do things like this; e.g. [Mergely](http://www.mergely.com/x5LJ4SPi/).

Comment: At least in C# it's fairly common for a question to involve 20-30 lines. I don't think there's any way to avoid this.

Comment: [Alternatives are available](http://www.mergely.com/x5LJ4SPi/)

Comment: ... so I suggest a feature to add to this site and your response is "There are other sites."? That doesn't really make much sense to me. :) I'm just giving a suggestion to improve the chat on *this* site.

Comment: Well, I did understand your request... just that I don't think this is what chat is for or should be for and instances of this happening are isolated (with a diff being necessary even less so). I'd also like chat to have a `todo` list and a grocery shopping checklist so that I don't spend too much time in chat and forget to buy milk. Doesn't seem like a reasonable request to ask for that...

Comment: Except that SO already has a diff tool for questions when they have been edited... It doesn't have to do lists.